# Weird PHP magic getter on an array

Tags: php

I have weird issues with magic getter/isset.
I have myObject that defines magic getter/isset:

```
private $_data = array();

public function __get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) return $this->_data[$name];
    throw new Exception($name.': property doesn\'t exist.');
}

public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->_data[$name]);
}
```

If I call:

```
isset($myObject->notExisting);
empty($myObject->notExisting);
```

I have correct behaviour (__isset() is called), while if I call:

```
isset($myObject->notExisting['ok']));
empty($myObject->notExisting['ok']));
```

__isset() is not called while __get() is.

This seems weird to me as PHP should first check for $myObject->notExisting existence before trying to get it, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset):

> __isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.

in `isset($myObject->notExisting);` isset applies to the `notExisting` property of `$myObject`.

in `isset($myObject->notExisting['ok']));` isset applies to `ok` element of `$myObject->notExisting` array.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour.

Let's stripe this:

```
isset($myObject->notExisting['ok']));
```

This implies that $myObject->notExisting exists, because you want to get the object in the array with key 'ok'. So this will use the __get() method.

Comment: Thanks guys, both of your answers are fine to me